# How can I prove this statement by induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I would like to prove that
$2^0 + 2^{-1} + 2^{-2} +...+ 2^{-n} \leq 2$
by induction.

I got the induction basis as $2^0 \leq 2$, but I couldn't find a induction step that could help me to prove that.

Any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: Can you use the fact that the sum on the left is monotonically increasing and is a geometric sum with limit value 2?

Comment: you should put the elipses "..." is the statement.  $2^0 + 2^{-1} + ... + 2^{-n}$.  Otherwise what you are actually stating (obviously not your intent) that $2^0 + 2^{-1} + 2^{-2} + 2^{-n} = 1.75 + 2^{-n} \le 2 \iff 2^{-n} \le \frac 14$ which is not true for $n = 0, 1$ and trivial to prove if $n \ge 2$  and overall a very boring and not worth noting observation.

Comment: My comments are outdated, so I deleted them to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

${\bf Hint}\ \ 1 + 1/2 + 1/4+\cdots + 1/2^n\ \le\ 2,\ $ when divided by $\,2\,$

$\Rightarrow\ 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8+\cdots + 1/2^{n+1} \le 1$

Adding $\,1\,$ to the prior equation we infer $\,P_n \Rightarrow\, P_{n+1}$

**Remark** $\ $ Essentially we exploited a recurrence  for the expression $\,f_n$

$$  f_{n+1} = 1 + f_n/2,\quad f_0 = 1 $$

therefore $\ \color{#c00}{f_n \le 2}\,\Rightarrow\, f_{n+1} = 1+\color{#c00}{f_n}/2\, \le\, 1+\color{#c00}{2}/2\,\le\, 2$

that is  $\ \ f_n \le 2\,\Rightarrow\, f_{n+1}\le 2,\ $ which is the induction step $\,P_n\Rightarrow P_{n+1}$

Comment: To be rigorous one should replace the ellipses by summation operators.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those cases where in order for induction to work, you actually need to prove something stronger. Try replacing $\leq 2$ with $=2-2^{-n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Base case:

$n = 0$

$2^0 = 1 < 2$.  Okay.

Just for good measure a second base case:

$n = 1$

$2^0 +  2^{-1} = 1 + 1/2 < 2$. Okay.

Induction step:

Assume true for $n = k$

So $2^0 + 2^{-1} + .... + 2^{-k} \le 2$ so

$2^0 + 2^{-1} + ..... + 2^{-k} + 2^{-(k+1)} \le 2 + \frac 1{2^{k+1}}$...

Hmmm, that doesn't work.  Can.  I prove *stronger*.

Note: $2^0 = 1 = 2- \frac 1{2^0} < 2$

$2^0 + 2^1 = 1 + \frac 12 = 2 - \frac 1{2^1} < 2$

Maybe I can prov $2^0 + 2^{-1} + ..... + 2^{-n} = 2 - \frac 1{2^n} < 2$ instead.

Well, I've shown the base cases.  Induction:

$n = k$

So $2^0 + 2^{-1} + .... + 2^{-k} = 2 - \frac 1{2^{k}} \le 2$ so

$2^0 + 2^{-1} + ..... + 2^{-k} + 2^{-(k+1)} = 2 -\frac 1{2^{k}} +\frac 1{2^{k+1}}=$

$2 -(\frac 1{2^{k}} -\frac 1{2^{k+1}} ) = 2 - \frac{2 - 1}{2^{k+1}} = 2  -\frac 1{2^{k+1}} < 2$

Done.

(As it's a stronger result the weaker result $2^0 + 2^{-1} + .... + 2^{-n} \le 2$ must also be true.)

Answer (score -1):

$2^0 + 2^{-1} + 2^{-2} +... + 2^{-n} <= 2$

For the first case note that $2^0 \leq 2$ is true and also $0 \leq 2- 2^0$. In fact $2- 2^0 = 2^0$

Next notice that $2^k - 2^{k-1} = 2^{k-1}$

You can prove by induction that $2-(2^0 + 2^{-1} + 2^{-2} +...+ 2^{-n}) = 2^{-n}$

Comment: What you state is false: the OP might have made a bad mistake of notation, but why picking it up in the answer?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli  Why not point out that the OP forgot ellipses rather than pretending the OP was deliberately stating a false statement?

Comment: @Hugh The OP forgot to include the very important ellipses "..." make that statement quite different that what either the OP or you typed.

Comment: Ah, screw it.  I don't usually like editting others posts but as the ellipses were obviously intended and without them the statement is completely different and as people are pointing it out but not actually addressing the issue but instead obfuscating... I edited the ellipses in everywhere.

Comment: @fleablood Making the question is not up to me. I might make it better looking, but not change its meaning. Since an answer is something that ideally goes from a more experienced person to a less experienced one, I think reproducing there the mistakes of algebra and notation particularly wrong and uninstructive.

Comment: I agree in theory but pretending the OP's intention was to have a completely different statement rather than simply acknowledging and pointing  the obvious issue that the OP left out ellipses is misleading and disingenuous and ultimately will cause much more confusion when the OP simply will not see his error and not understand what you are talking about.  I don't like editting other's posts because I don't want to second guess the posters meaning but this derailing of pretending the OP is trying to prove $1.75 + 2^{-n} \le 2$ was getting ridiculous.